# Horror story about a lonely man whose life is tied to that of a snake in his bedroom

Tags: story-identification, horror

The protagonist is a lonely man, a loser in life with no relatives or friends. One day he finds a snake in his room. Being rejected everywhere he starts building a relationship with the snake. His life is tied with that of the snake. Fifties short story.

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but [this is apparently a Filipino tradition.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/29791942?seq=1)

Comment: And by "his life is tied with that of the snake", do you mean that, say, injuries to the snake are reflected on him and vice versa, or that if one dies, the other will?

Comment: FuzzyBoots Yes ,exactly